# Application can't save file under documents folder

Tags: windows-10, access-control, my-documents

I have a drawing app Pencil on the Win10 Pro, converted from Win7. I don't remember if I used this app after the conversion but it used to save file "SAVE/SAVE AS" under `Documents`. But now this is not happening. I get exception/warning

[image]

I Can save it in other locations, like `c:\temp`. Also can't create `New Folder` via App dialog. In contrast, "MS Word" application can perform all same actions fine. So, this is only isolated to Pencil.  **I am admin on my machine**

I already uninstalled and reinstalled it. No luck.
Any ideas?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas if this is so simple, please post the answer. I will even upvote it if it solves my problem. BTW, I am admin on my machine and as I posted above^^^ other apps don't have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot looks like the dots are actually part of the containing folder name.

If this is in fact the case, then note that Windows folder names cannot end with a dot. They can contain dots, but if it ends with a dot, the last dot is interpreted as a delimiter for an extension (ignored).

This could explain both your inability to save to this folder and to create new folders within it: `bob....` would evaluate to `bob...` and then "file not found."

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what "dots" you have in mind. There is a file name. No folder has any dots in the name. There is a button "SAVE". There is a button "New Folder" - both don't work when trying to save under "Documents". Outside Documents - it works

Comment: look at your screen shot. there are a series of dots immediately preceeding the slash and desired filename in the error message. it is plausible the error message is eliding part of the complete file path for space when displaying it, which is why I say "if this is the case".

Comment: This is just app, or windows place dots there instead of real name to fit file name on one line. In reality the full name is much longer. There no dots in the actual path